# QNetworkConfigurationManager results intepretation

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qt5

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager ncm;
ncm.updateConfigurations();

auto nc = ncm.allConfigurations();
```

The QNetworkConfigurationManager is used to list the wifi status. The result however (in windows) not only shows connected to the particular wifi which is connected but also to the "Wi-Fi". So basically it gives back two connected QNetworkConfiguration objects. One with the actual wifi name and another with the name "Wi-Fi". What is the reason it shows this Wi-Fi name?
Tx

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the configurations by setting a flag to `ncm.allConfigurations()` call.

May be you can try as shown below for the active connection.

```
auto nc = ncm.allConfigurations(QNetworkConfiguration::Active);
```

Refer
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkconfiguration.html#StateFlag-enum

Comment: actually the problem is it gives two entries as active, one with the actual wifi name ("xxx" and one with hardware interface name ("Wi-Fi").